# bash script | ffmpeg encoding videos + hardsub

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, subtitle

Hello stackoverflow ,

i'm using this bash script to encode videos (*.mp4) in same folder

Script :

```
    #!/bin/bash   

for i in *.mp4;
  do name=`echo "${i%.*}"`;
  echo $name;
  ffmpeg -i "${i}" -vcodec libx264 -b:v 1800k  -maxrate 2200k -acodec aac -movflags +faststart -tune zerolatency "${name}".enc.mp4;
done
```

my question how i can add capability to hard subtitle ? automatically .

Example :

i have 20 video (video1.mp4 .. video2.mp4 ...) and 20 subtitle (video1.ass .. video2.ass video3.ass ..) in same folder .

how i can do it with bash script ?

- hard sub in ffmpeg ** -vf "ass=video1.ass" **

Thanks all ,

Comment: OT: `name=\`echo "${i%.*}"\`;` could be written much more simply as `name=${i%.*}`

Comment: Thanks , 
how i can do "for loop" with 2 variable ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean, exactly, but you should probably ask a new question with a few details about what you are trying to accomplish.